# apache spark agg( ) function

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

For a sample dataframe `scholor`,

```
scala> scholor.show

| id|  name|age|sal|base|
```

For above, both below, gives same output. What will be use of agg() then. It just for name.

```
scala> scholor.groupBy("age").sum("base").show      /*with out agg */

scala> scholor.groupBy("age").agg(sum("base")).show        /* with agg */
```

```
+---+---------+
|age|sum(base)|
+---+---------+
```

Does `agg()` need any varargs as arguments?
What is need of `agg()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need to agg? The result is the sum of bases grouped per age. That is an aggregation already.

Comment: @JoostdenBoer : yes. sum , min,max,mean,etc.... are aggregation functions already. then why dataframe api provide agg( ) method. i think, it meant for something .... searchin for that something !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order write `.sum` this method has to exist. It is hardcoded on the API. Using `.agg` you can provide other aggregating functions, `sum("column")` is just one of them.

Answer (score 4):

From the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7955b3962ac46b89564e0613db7bea98a1478bf2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1793) for `agg`, "ds.agg(...) is a shorthand for ds.groupBy().agg(...)".

---

Aggregate functions `avg`, `max`, `min`, `sum`, and `count` are not methods that can be called on DataFrames:

```
scala> my_df.min("column")
<console> error: value min is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

`agg` is a DataFrame method that accepts those aggregate functions as arguments:

```
scala> my_df.agg(min("column"))
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [min(column): double]
```

Calling `groupBy()` on a DataFrame returns a RelationalGroupedDataset which has those aggregate functions as methods (source code for [`groupBy`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7955b3962ac46b89564e0613db7bea98a1478bf2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1534)):

```
scala> my_df.groupBy().min("column")
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [min(column): double]
```